# PHP create a file without fopen

Tags: php, fopen

Is there a way to create a file with PHP when `fopen` is disabled?  Other functions to access the file system are enabled such as `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: How is fopen disabled? Which error message does it result in if you try to use it? If there is a list of disabled functions, tell us. Reduces guessing alternatives.

Comment: seems to me like the problem is with opening url's. working with local files should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look up file_put_contents()... though if fopen has been disabled it may also be disabled. Getting and putting files are two different things from a permissions perspective.

And if fopen has been disabled, I can't imagine that exec() hasn't also been disabled.

Comment: file_put_contents() did the trick.  I wasn't aware that if the file didn't exist, then it would be created.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
touch('file.txt');
```

Maybe the simplest.

Comment: I like this answer because it can be run to ensure the file exists immediately preceding another file manipulation command without having to add messy checks.