# Create a file with PHP without opening it

Tags: php, file, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP create a file without fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510161/php-create-a-file-without-fopen)

I want to create a file without fopen function because it opens the file. Is it possible or I have no choice but fopen?
I'm writing a *Checker* Class that will make sure that some files exist and has write permission. If one file does not exist, I just want it to be created. This class won't manipulate any file content.

Comment: You just need to open it and save it then close it. You can't just create a file in PHP. For the existing, just use `if (!file_exist($file)) { }`

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do here - PHP does not have sophisticated locking semantics hence understanding the objective is key to recommending a solution. If it's for a lock file, then that entails a fixed name for the file - but you can't really avoid most race conditons without an external arbitrator. OTOH if you just want any old file, then tempnam() will do this - the process is not completely atomic - but sufficiently so.

Comment: I'm trying to create a file without open it. It's like when you right click inside a folder and create new txt file. The file doesn't open to you. It's just created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`touch`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) function. To quote from the documentation:

> Attempts to set the access and modification times of the file named in
>   the filename parameter to the value given in time. Note that the
>   access time is always modified, regardless of the number of
>   parameters.
>
> If the file does not exist, it will be created.

Comment: I fixed your answer and saved it from community deletion. In future please provide more than just a link.

Comment: @Kev Thank you for the edit. I think Gordon is correct about this being a duplicate - the dupe has very similar answers as well.

Comment: @Gordon - it's not the greatest dupe I've seen, think I'll skip on the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can check the existence of a file with `file_exists` (it even tells you it's a regular file, and not a directory but it will also yield a positive answer if the object you look at is a symlink that points to a proper file). You can also look at the file permissions with `fileperms()` and you probably want also want to be looking at user and group of the file to understand whether you could be writing to it.